# patch 10266 not installing in magento 1.9.3.3

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-10266

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

```
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 76 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 99 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Grid/Renderer/Notice.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 43 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 108 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 51 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 162 (different line endings).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 179 (different line endings).
Hunk #4 FAILED at 397 (different line endings).
4 out of 4 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 37 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 75 (different line endings).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 109 (different line endings).
Hunk #4 FAILED at 119 (different line endings).
4 out of 4 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 33 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/QueueController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 63 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/TemplateController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 142 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 284 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 709 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Abstract.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 235 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 91 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 136 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 158 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 467 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Data.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 74 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 82 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 152 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Serializer/Adapter/PhpCode.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 120 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 151 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/file.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 33 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 45 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 70 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 58 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/toolbar.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 75 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login-simple.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 58 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 46 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 53 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 75 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 130 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/install/default/default/template/install/create_admin.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 66 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
checking file downloader/template/login.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 35 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
```

Comment: This will happen due to dependency  on the other patches or try to update the core code with updated code at hunk point files with getting the updated pack from magento which helps you to resolve that

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problème with your line breaks :
you need to be with the format LF (Unix) and not CR + LF (Windows) or CR (Mac).

Use the command `dos2unix` to convert your file then try again your install.

Comment: i am using Windows which command should i use?

Comment: You're using Windows, but your Magento is deploy on Unix server or Linux VM, isn't it ?